# VLookup Code Error in form - Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error, vlookup

I have started exploring VBA and I am stuck on the below code.

Please help me out.

Basically I am trying to Vlookup data from 1st sheet and 2nd sheet and generating lookup value in 3rd sheet.

## Sheet 1

[image]

## Sheet 2

[image]

## Sheet 3

[image]

```
Sub Semi_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'********************************************
'*** RESPONDENT WISE DATA PREPARATION ***
'********************************************
        
Sheets(1).Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Columns(1)
Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Rows(1)

Sheets(3).Select
Cells(1, 1).Select

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
mrow = ActiveCell.Row
mcolumn = ActiveCell.Column

For j = 2 To mcolumn
For i = 2 To mrow
Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(2).Range("A:MAA"), 2, False)
Next i
Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: For Clarification, I am getting lookup value for 1st column, but when it comes for 2nd  column, it is not able show lookup value form sheet 2. Please refer attachment of Sheet 1, Sheet 2 and Sheet 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that you should be aware of:
1) You turn off screen updating, but never turn it back on.  I recommend keeping it on until your code works so that you can see what is happening.
2) It is best to declare your variables.  Mrow, Mcolumn, i and j should be declared as long.
3) Try to avoid using `Select` as much as possible.  You become dependent on your cursor location and it usually ends up not working well, which is why you are getting the error.  You are trying to select `Cells(1,1)`, but you do not declare the sheet you want to select from.  It is assuming that you want to select from `Sheets(1)`, but you can't because you have selected `Sheets(3)`. 4) Indent your code.  It is easier to read and easier to follow your loops and if/then statements.

A rewrite of your existing code would look like this:

```
Sub Semi_Open()

    Dim mrow As Long
    Dim mcolumn As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Sheets(1).Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Columns(1)
    Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Rows(1)

    mrow = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    mcolumn = Sheets(3).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 2 To mcolumn
        For i = 2 To mrow
            Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(2).Range("A:MAA"), 2, False)
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```